# Find a method using parameter types where parameters are generic

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am sure this is a duplicate, but I can not find the answer.

`System.Linq.Queryable` has a method with following signature:

```
public static int Count<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
    Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate);
```

How do I use `System.Type::GetMethod` method to get this method?

```
typeof(System.Linq.Queryable).GetMethod("Count", type[]{ ??? });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
var method = typeof (System.Linq.Queryable).GetMethods().Single(a=>a.Name == "Count" && a.GetParameters().Length == 2);
```

And after, if you want to invoke it

```
method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof (YourType));
```

For additional, it could be filtered (for different selects):

```
var sel1 = typeof (Queryable).GetMethods().Single(a => a.Name == "Select"
                && a.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(object), typeof(object)).GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == typeof(Expression<Func<object, object>>));

var sel2 = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Single(a => a.Name == "Select"
                && a.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(object), typeof(object)).GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == typeof(Expression<Func<object,int, object>>));
```

Comment: In this case I can, but this won't work with Select (that has two overloads - two parameters each).

Comment: If you have not Queryable type, but another generic type (not type with generic methods) you can use 

    public class MyGenType<T>
    {
        public void Select(){}
        public void Select(T withGenPar){}
        public void Select(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression){}
        
        public static MethodInfo SecondSelect{
            get { return typeof (MyGenType<T>).GetMethod("Select", new[] {typeof (T)}); }}
    }

or 
            var seconds = typeof (MyGenType<int>).GetMethod("Select", new[] {typeof (int)});

Answer (score 1):

The method with the least effort would probably be to capture the method you want with an expression tree, then delve in to find the method reference.  You can do this once to get the generic method definition, then cache the result and reuse it as necessary.

```
Expression<Func<IQueryable<int>, int>> getCount = p => p.Count();
MethodInfo countMethod = ((MethodCallExpression)getCount.Body).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
```

This has the benefit of being *somewhat* resilient to API changes (e.g., the addition of more "Count" members); the method returned will be whatever method your expression binds to at compile time.

You could extract this behavior out into utility methods if you like:

```
public static MethodInfo MethodOf(Expression<Action> accessExpression, bool dropTypeArguments = false)
{
    if (accessExpression == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("accessExpression");

    var callExpression = accessExpression.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    if (callExpression == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Expression body must be a method call.", "accessExpression");

    var method = callExpression.Method;

    if (dropTypeArguments && method.IsGenericMethod)
        return method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();

    return method;
}

public static MethodInfo MethodOf<TInstance>(Expression<Action<TInstance>> call, bool dropTypeArguments = false)
{
    if (call == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("call");

    var callExpression = call.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    if (callExpression == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Expression body must be a method call.", "call");

    var method = callExpression.Method;

    if (dropTypeArguments && method.IsGenericMethod)
        return method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();

    return method;
}
```

Use the first overload for static-style invocations and the latter for instance-style invocations, e.g.:

```
var countMethod1 = Extensions.MethodOf(() => Queryable.Count(default(IQueryable<int>)), dropTypeArguments: true);
var countMethod2 = Extensions.MethodOf((IQueryable<int> p) => p.Count(), dropTypeArguments: true);
```

To preserve the type arguments (e.g., to resolve `Count<int>()` instead of `Count<T>()`) just omit the `dropTypeArguments: true` argument or set it to `false`.

Note that these aren't terribly comprehensive; they will not, for example, drop generic parameters on the declaring type (only on the method itself).  Feel free to use, extend, or throw away :).

Comment: Do you know for sure there is no way to use GetMethod with exact parameter types using .net API itself?

Comment: In general, yes, but the not for generic methods.  `GetMethod()` will not attempt to bind generic type arguments.  You would need to use something like `GetMethods()` or `FindMember()` and iterate over the results, checking the argument and return types until you find a match.  But doing that _correctly_ is cumbersome, and the easy solution (see @pil0t's answer) is fragile; but at least his solution of using `Single()` will throw if the method becomes ambiguous in a future release.  My solution, however, will get you an exact match easily and pretty reliably.

Comment: In my case types are not know at compile time.

Comment: Then substitute any type (I used `int`) and drop the type arguments to get the generic method definition.  When you know your runtime type, call `MakeGenericMethod()` with the correct type to bind the method.

Comment: (all of the examples in my answer will give you the generic definition of `Count<TSource>()` regardless of what `IQueryable<>` instantiation you used to resolve it)